# Fees in proto 003?

Tags: protocol, consensus, storage, fees, gas

Fees have been updated from proto 002 to proto 003.

Is there a reference document available somewhere that is indicating fee information for tezos proto 003 ?

Comment: You can also have a look at https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/436/118

Comment: Still haven't got around the different types of fees and how fees work. Some websites say they are optional. It would be nice to have a post explaining in detail the types of fee, why low/mid/high, what is gas, etc.

Comment: I explain the types of fees in the beginning of my answer. Can you please tell me what is unclear and i will update ? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information is available from the official documentation in the « Baker » section

https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html

The basic formula specifies that fees are now dependent on 3 parameters: a fixed minimum fee, a fee by storage unit and a fee by gas unit (reflection the cost of performing calculations). Those 3 parameters are not set at protocol level can be set at the node level by Bakers depending on their preference. The protocol constraints the maximum size and gas in a block however.

Also in eztz doc we can also get this info

https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md

Fees are in mutez, and should be at least:
minfees >= 100 + (gas * .1) + (opbytes * 1)
Reveals

```
•   storage_limit : 0
•   gas_limit : 10000
•   opbytes : ~169
•   fee : 1269
```

Delegations

```
•   storage_limit : 0
•   gas_limit : 10000
•   opbytes : ~157
•   fee : 1257
```

Originations

```
•   storage_limit : 257
•   gas_limit : 10000
•   opbytes : ~185
•   fee : ~1285
```

Incurs an additional .257tz origination burn fee (for the source)

Transactions to KT1/active implicit account*

```
•   storage_limit : 0
•   gas_limit : 10100
•   opbytes : ~162
•   fee : 1272
```

Transactions to inactive implicit account

```
•   storage_limit : 257
•   gas_limit : 10100
•   opbytes : ~162
•   fee : 1272
```

Incurs an additional .257tz origination burn fee (for the source)

Emptying an implicit account
    •   gas_limit: add 160
    •   fee: add 16

Also note the following

```
•   opbytes is a rough estimate for basic operations. You need to use the actual size of the serialized operation bytes, which includes the 32 byte header and the 64 byte signature.

•   An inactive implicity account is a tz account with nil (0) balance which isn't registered as a delegate/baker
```

Answer (score 2):

The fees have been updated for proto004 (athens) please have a look here going forward

https://github.com/keefertaylor/TezosKit/blob/master/docs/AthensProtocolFees.md