# How does tezos-client compute a transaction fee?

Tags: operation, tezos-client, fee

When running a transaction such as `tezos-client transfer 1 from alice to bob`, how  does the client computes the transaction fee?

Comment: You can also have a look at this one https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/106/118

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fee computation follows [the formula](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html#more-details-on-fees-and-cost-model).

The only subtle thing here is that the fee itself can affect the size of the operation in binary. This usually doesn't matter, but to handle the general case, the client currently loops:

1. Start with the draft op with fee set to zero (with its gas_limit and storage_limit chosen appropriately).
2. Measure the op size in binary and compute the required fee according to the formula. (If this is the first/only op in a batch, add the [fixed overhead](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/27c5bc86c0f7d3d5be0e285fa6cf388745a1b6bf/src/proto_alpha/lib_client/injection.ml#L393) for a batch of operations here too.)
3. If the fee in the op is big enough, we're done. Otherwise, update the fee in the op, and go to #2.

This happens in [patch_fee in injection.ml](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/27c5bc86c0f7d3d5be0e285fa6cf388745a1b6bf/src/proto_alpha/lib_client/injection.ml#L388).

Comment: I am not sure it uses this code. Instead, I think it calls the node through RPCs, this is explained in the blog post cited by my reply.

Comment: RPCs are indeed used to estimate gas and storage usage, and more, but there is no RPC for calculating the minimum fee. The code I linked is used.

Comment: (To see this happening, try `tezos-client -l` without specifying a fee, as in the blog post. You will notice that the `run_operation` is called with 0 fee, and then `preapply` is mysteriously called with the correct minimal fee, not returned yet by any RPC, but calculated by the client after `run_operation`.)

Comment: Oh yes, I thought it was about gas and burn. I will delete my answer.