# What is gas on the Tezos network?

Tags: gas

This question is related to the fact that I have no understanding for what reason need to increase the gas limit, what will the increase affect and why it is impossible to leave the limit as it is?
I would like to hear the answer in a fairly simple, but as complete as possible form, what is gas, so that simple users of the network can understand

Answer (score 8):

Gas represents computational cost related to a transaction, e.g. gas for basic transactions are about 10,000 units, where as more costly transactions that invoke smart contracts can cost a lot more.

Currently there is a fixed gas limit per operation of 400,000 units, and a fixed gas limit per block of 4,000,000 units. This is quite limiting for transactions (especially smart contract calls), for example currently a single block can only contain ~400 basic transactions (4,000,000 / 10,000) which equates to a TPS of about 6.66.

The gas limits are quite low in my opinion, and an increase would greatly help to improve TPS and viability of more complex smart contracts.

Comment: What can one gas unit be equated to?
How does the protocol calculate the required amount of gas for transactions of a smart contract?

Comment: It's coded into the protocol, e.g. an amount of gas is assigned to different instructions. It's something that can be tweaked, benchmarked and optimized. Gas costs are meant to equate to computation, e.g. if one instruction takes twice as much computation time/resources, it should consume twice as much gas. Gas in general still needs optimizations, I believe the initial values were conservative in nature.

Comment: And do gas costs also have a direct effect on transaction costs in XTZ?

Comment: Including a transaction into a block costs computation - e.g. the baker would need to validate that the sender has enough balance etc. Gas cost is a nanotez - this comes out to being ~0.0014 tez for a basic transaction.

Comment: @MarcB yes you can check here for details for costs/fees in tezos proto 003 https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/106/fees-in-proto-003