# Burn fee for empty account

Tags: fees, fee

Does `.257` burn fee for new account needs to be put in the `transaction` operation?

```
    operations.contents.push({
      kind: 'transaction',
      counter,
      fee: min_fee + burn_fee, // <-- here?
      gas_limit,
      storage_limit,
      amount,
      source,
      destination
    })
```

The sender should first query (through RPC) to see if the `destination` address is new and adjust fee accordingly? That's a bit tricky.

I'll have as fee something like `minimum_fee=1257 + burn_fee=257000`
What if my destination address is a smart contract? my `minimum_fee` must be adjusted?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "burn fee". Fees and burns are different, completely separate, things. A fee is paid to the baker, a burn is destroyed. The burn is accounted for in the storage_limit. I'm not sure what specific question you really want to ask.

Comment: I read about that "burn fee" in another answer https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/106/fees-in-proto-003 needed to activate new account. Whatever you wanna call it I mean "activation fee"

Answer (score 4):

Fees and burns are different, completely separate, things. A fee is paid to the baker, a burn is destroyed.

The 0.257 burn for allocating a new implicit account is, indeed, a burn, representing the storage cost of maintaining an account in the node state indefinitely.

When an operation requires a storage burn, you must indicate in the `storage_limit` how much (measured in logical bytes) you are willing to burn (according to the constant cost_per_byte = 1000 mutez = 0.001 tez).

```
{
  kind: 'transaction',
  fee: min_fee,
  storage_limit: 257,
  ...
}
```

The `storage_limit: 257` says "I'm willing to burn up to 257*cost_per_byte = 0.257 tez for this operation".

Comment: what wasn't clear is that that '.257 burn fee should be kept as account balance. Thanks for reply.

Comment: When does an operation require a storage burn?

Comment: @arvidj when you're sending xtz to an account that has not been revealed on the chain yet.

Comment: @RoccoMusolino isn't the revealing another operation, when sending _from_ an account for the first time, which costs a fee (not burn)?