# transaction rejected by the mempool pre filter

Tags: transactions, mempool

I'm trying to broadcast this operation.
The first `reveal` operation went fine.
Now with this one:

```
{
  amount: "1000000"
  counter: "1179510"
  destination: "tz1......"
  fee: "1273"
  gas_limit: "10300"
  kind: "transaction"
  source: "tz1........"
  storage_limit: "300"
}
```

I'm having a an error `<txId> rejected by the mempool pre filter`.
The destination address is active.
The balance on my address is enough to cover the tx amount and any other fee.

Did I put wrong fee in the operation?
Can you guys explain what this error is and how to avoid it?

I hardcoded `gas_limit`, `storage_limit` and `fee` to those values..

Answer (score 3):

Right, your fee is not high enough.

Next time you think something like "is this the wrong fee?", let your next thought be like "I will try increasing the fee to see what happens."

Hardcoding the fee is not a great idea. At best, you will pay unnecessarily high fees, losing some mutez. At worst, this will happen.

There are [docs](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/protocols/003_PsddFKi3.html#baker) and other questions here about how to compute the required fee, e.g. [How does tezos-client compute a transaction fee?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/436/how-does-tezos-client-compute-a-transaction-fee) and [Fees in proto 003?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/q/106).

Despite the list of approximate fees given in the [TezTech doc](https://github.com/TezTech/eztz/blob/master/PROTO_003_FEES.md), you must do the calculation if you want the minimal fee, because it depends on the specific details of the operation.

Comment: what about the burnt fee to activate an account, do that need to be summed to the operation fee? or left as balance on the account?

Comment: I answered that when you [asked it before](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/962).